# Accessing item in tuple nested in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, nested, tuples

So I'm a little confused about the dictionary this [function](http://api.rethinkrobotics.com/baxter_interface/html/index.html) returns. (The endpoint_pose function)

It seems to be a dictionary, with nested dictionary or tuple I am not sure. What the function returns is this

```
{'position': Point(x=0.7938064310002948, y=0.4000015952566877, z=0.28522708748065545), 'orientation': Quaternion(x=-0.18674837754140436, y=0.7484662663927322, z=-0.5955181308876427, w=0.22423524999844527)}
```

How can I access the z coordinate position?

Comment: @laurant...Is there a problem with the below provided answers?...You should give us a feedback if none of them did solve your issue..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indexing a namedtuple nested in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995861/indexing-a-namedtuple-nested-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result looks like a dictionary with objects.  Look at how datetime looks:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today()
datetime.date(2016, 6, 24)
```

To access variable **z** in the object is a simple dictionary lookup and accessing the attribute:

```
>>> result = {'position': Point(x=0.7938064310002948, y=0.4000015952566877, z=0.28522708748065545), 'orientation': Quaternion(x=-0.18674837754140436, y=0.7484662663927322, z=-0.5955181308876427, w=0.22423524999844527)}
>>> result['position'].z
0.28522708748065545
```

Good luck!

**Edit**: @iron-fist does provide good information on the type of objects in the dictionary.  If you'd like to learn more about [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), look at Iron Fist's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021882/accessing-item-in-tuple-nested-in-dictionary-python/38022021#38022021).

Answer (score 1):

What you get as a return is a dictionary with [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s, so to access the z-element, simply:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
Quaternion = namedtuple('Quaternion', ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'])

mycoords = {
    'position': Point(x=0.7938064310002948, y=0.4000015952566877, z=0.28522708748065545),
    'orientation': Quaternion(x=-0.18674837754140436, y=0.7484662663927322, z=-0.5955181308876427, w=0.22423524999844527)
    }

print(mycoords['position'].z)  # -> 0.28522708748065545
print(mycoords['orientation'].z)  # -> -0.5955181308876427
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Point` is a class (or `namedtuple` or whatever) with a `z` attribute (the `repr` can be deceiving, but usually not like this), you can look up by key, then access attributes normally:

```
mydict['position'].z
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't actually go to any function (due to the frames), but I'm guessing it's this one you're speaking of:

http://api.rethinkrobotics.com/baxter_interface/html/baxter_interface.limb.Limb-class.html#endpoint_pose

Either way, the function returns a dictionary with two different [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s. You'd access the z coordinate position by e.g.:

```
pose = limb.endpoint_pose()
z_coord = pose['position'].z
```