# Indexing a namedtuple nested in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, namedtuple

I'm looking to store a named tuple inside a dictionary. That parts easy. I don't know how to reference an individual bit in the namedtuple following that though.

I know that I could just use a dictionary and make life easier, but in the case where you have values you know you don't want to change, it'd be nice to use a namedtuple here (more so just out of interest - I realize strings are immutable as well).

```
from collections import namedtuple

Rec = namedtuple('name', ['First', 'Middle', 'Last'])
name = Rec('Charles', 'Edward', 'Bronson')

info = dict(identity=name)

print(name.First)
print(info['identity'])
print(type(info['identity']))
```

Results:

```
Charles
name(First='Charles', Middle='Edward', Last='Bronson')
<class '__main__.name'>
```

I expect to be able to access `name.First` through calling `info['identity'][name.First]` or something similar, but I can't seem to index inside the nested namedtuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you probably know, namedtuples support multiple types of indexing

- `tuple[0]` returns the first field (order is defined from the list of fields you gave during the `namedtuple` definition)
- `tuple.field_name` returns the field named `field_name`

`info['identity']` is the namedtuple you want to index, so let's go :)

```py
print(info['identity'] == name)
# True
print(info['identity'].First)
# Charles
# or
print(info['identity'][0])
# Charles

# OR, splitting the operations
name_field = info['identity']
print(name_field.First)
```

Comment: I knew it would be so simple, all the combinations I'd tried for the second statement just wouldn't work. Thanks Gregoire!!